# Dynamic dataSet values In BIRT

Tags: birt

I am using BIRT. In my dataset, sometimes my query returns 5 columns, sometimes 6 or more than that i.e basically, my dataset is dynamic. How to prepare a report using dynamic dataSet?

Answer (score 0):

BIRT provides a Design Engone API to create or modify report designs at runtime. You can use this API in Java or within Javascript event handler (report.beforeFactory()).
http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/deapi.php

On the following page you can find examples how to use the API: https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-dynamic-columns/wiki/Home